# Optional Date Parameters

Tags: parameters, parameter-passing, reporting, pentaho

I'm using Pentaho Report Designer 3.9.4 and a db2 database.  I have 4 variables that I need to pass in to my Pentaho report through a stored procedure call, 3 of which are driven by the user.

```
CALL SCHEMA.STORED_PROCEDURE ('DATA', ${START_DATE}, ${END_DATE}, ${PARM_YEAR})
```

The rows of data are provided by the first variable 'DATA' which will be hard coded.  I have a drop down box parameter PARM_YEAR that allows the user to choose and drill down to a specific year.  I also have date picker parameters START_DATE and END_DATE that receives the start and end date values from the user retrieving the desired results from that specified date range.  The PARM_YEAR and date range parameters (START/END_DATE) need to be optional.  If the user selects a year with the drop down parameter PARM_YEAR then the report will produce the results and vice versa for the date picker parameters.  In order to retrieve the results for the date range selected the PARM_YEAR parameter must equal zero.

```
CALL SCHEMA.STORED_PROCEDURE ('DATA', ${START_DATE}, ${END_DATE}, 0)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.  Make the PARAM_YEAR parameter optional (not mandatory). Then add a new hidden parameter to the report and give it a post-processing formula of "=IFNA([PARAM_YEAR]; 0)" to provide a value when your year is not set. Or list the zero option as one of the selections in your PARAM_YEAR if it is a drop-down parameter.